# Create Plane on line with same angle it was making on another line?

Tags: math, vector, three.js, webgl, plane

I have one plane mesh which will be rotated by user for his desire orientation then I have line which I create so it will pass through that plane. Now user can rotate plane mesh using transform controls as he want. After rotation we have final orientation of plane now that plane normal and line which passed through center of plane have some angle.

Another line I have is in a completely different position than the first line. I want to create plane on this line which will have same orientation as previous plane and make same angle as previous plane normal is making with its center line.

I don't want to change the position of the lines as both lines position are important.

How Do I proceed I tried Cloning old plane and placed that plane on new line but it is not making the same angle as previous one.

Here is the [Link](https://glitch.com/%7Edelicate-concise-hospital) to Live code sandbox I created.

Press A to create plane on second line.

Comment: This is equivalent to "given a line and an angle, how can I construct a vector that makes that angle with that line?" There are many such vectors; do you care which one is chosen?

Comment: @Beta okay I got your point. I just calculated plane normal and then calculated the angle that normal is making with line. Then for another line I am calculating vector of that line and then rotating that vector with same angle which I calculated.